# Pass function with args and return value to another function

Tags: c++

Is it possible to pass function with arguments like this:

```
int func(int num)
{
 return num;
}
```

to this function:

```
        template<class T>
        auto addTask(T task) -> std::future<decltype(task())>
        {
            auto wrapper = std::make_shared<std::packaged_task<decltype(task()) ()>>(std::move(task));
            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mEventMutex);
                mTasks.emplace([=] {
                    (*wrapper)();
                });
            }
            mEventVar.notify_one();
            return wrapper->get_future();            
        }
```

I know how pass function without agrs like this:

```
void func()
{}
```

It will be just:

```
addTask(func);
```

but can't find where to place args. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) that calls the function:

```
addTask([some_value]()
{
    func(some_value);
});
```

---

Or rewrite `addTask` to use [template parameter packs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) for possible arguments:

```
template<typename Func, typename ...Args>
auto addTask(Func task, Args... arguments) -> std::future<decltype(task(arguments...))>
{
    auto wrapper = std::make_shared<std::packaged_task<decltype(task(arguments...)) (Args...)>>(std::move(task));
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mEventMutex);
        mTasks.emplace([=] {
            (*wrapper)(std::forward<Args>(arguments)...);
        });
    }
    mEventVar.notify_one();
    return wrapper->get_future();         
}

addTask(func, some_value);
```

Comment: Great answer, but when i compile it i have error: `error: no matching function for call to ‘forward(const int&)’`. I've also tried `(*wrapper)(std::forward<Args>(arguments)...);` but still had error: `binding reference of type ‘std::remove_reference<int>::type&’ {aka ‘int&’} to ‘const int’ discards qualifiers`. Where can be a problem?

Comment: @ADV To be honest I haven't tried it myself, nor do I have that much own experience with *perfect forwarding*. I did make an update to the answer that should hopefully solve your error.